# How to run a test class from another java class

Tags: java, gradle, testng, hudson

I have 3 java test classes.
 1. ListenerTest1.java
 2. ListenerTest2.java
 3. ListenerMain.java

Above two testfixture classes i.e  ListenerTest1.java and  ListenerTest2.java have test methods .
Also , having build.gradle file as :-

```
task automationTests(type: Test) {

    systemProperty 'serviceType', System.properties['serviceType']


    useTestNG {
        useDefaultListeners = true
        suiteXmlBuilder().suite(name: 'Testing case') {
            test(name: 'ServiceUITests', annotations: 'JDK', verbose: '1') {
                classes([:]) {

                    'class'(name: 'company.platform.ListenerMain')

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, while running my hudson job , it calls the task i.e **automationTests** and runs my ListenerMain class.
I need to add if/else condition in the ListenerMain class file which will differentiate to run the either of the above two classes mentioned i.e  ListenerTest1.java or  ListenerTest2.java on the basis of  System.property added in hudson job.

E.g

```
@Listeners(value = {PreconditionListener.class})
public class ListenerMain  {
    private static String serviceTypeUseParameter ;
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ListenerMain .class.getName());
    @BeforeClass
    //TestNg Annotation
    public void setup()
    {
        //#############   Hudson job parameter is serviceType ##########
serviceTypeUseParameter = System.getProperty("serviceType");
        if (serviceTypeUseParameter.equals("ListenerTest1Method")){
        // Run ListenerTest1 class
        }
        else{
        // Run ListenerTest2 class
        }
    }
}
```

What code need to be added for loading the class as per if/else condition ?
I can add main method in ListenerMain class if required.

Comment: refer this http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#runClasses(java.lang.Class...)

Comment: Could you share ListenerTest1 and ListenerTest2? What interfaces are they implementing?

Comment: There are no interfaces being used in either classes.
Its is simple TestFixture class which consists of testcases (test mtthods) using TestNg annotations.

Comment: @Jobin : Do JUnitCore will work for me as i'm using testng ?

Comment: refer this URL.. it will help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465695/how-to-run-testng-tests-from-main-in-an-executable-jar

Comment: @Jobin : Its really helped me ..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below code in if/else code. and within the `runClasses` method you can specify the test class.

```
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(ListenerTest1.class);
```

Comment: Why JUnitCore if i'm using TestNg ?

Comment: TestNG is a testing framework developed in the lines of JUnit and NUnit, i think u can use JUnitCore for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options in TestNG:

1. Implement an [annotation transformer](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/beanshell-and-testng/).
2. Use [BeanShell](https://www.infoq.com/news/2006/10/annotation-transformers)

Your annotation transformer would test the condition and then override the @Test annotation to add the attribute "enabled=false" if the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: As mentioned , i have 2 diff classes i.e ListenerTest1 and ListenerTest2, So i need to call a whole class from ListenerMain class.I think above links would help if one class consists of different groups methods.