# org.testng.TestNGException Cannot find class in classpath

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have a maven project where the following classes are present:

`src/main/java/App.java`

`src/test/java/AppTest.java`

The `testng.xml` is under the project root. I want to trigger tests from the `App.java` main method using the `testng.xml`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
        suites.add("testng.xml");
        testng.setTestSuites(suites);
        testng.run();
    }
```

Maven project is built still I am getting errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath.
```

Comment: Quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465695/how-to-run-testng-tests-from-main-in-an-executable-jar

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute java files from below main folder using testNG xml file.

> src/main/java

You should include all your test files in

> src/test/java

Then you can give the class name in testNG.xml file which is present in test folder. Then you would not get above error.

Comment: My test class is under src/test/java

Comment: @Saikat You should trigger tests from AppTest.java, not from  App.java as you have told in question

Comment: The test is in AppTest.java, I am trying to call it from main method, so that an executable jar can be used to run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

1) Steps to trace issues:

Create demo Test with following syntax and check execution:

```
class demo{    
  @Test
  public void testDemo(){
  System.out.println("Hello World");
  }     
}
```

If this has been work successfully, You have problem in your Test build structure.